# Karma launchers HTML5 APIs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, karma-runner

I can't find any documentation to confirm or deny that the karma launchers support HTML5 in the browsers. Yet my tests are failing because of some missing HTML5 capabilities. This happens for Firefox, Chrome and PhantomJS. However, everything works as expected when I use the actual browser.

I'm using the [mule-uploader](https://github.com/cinely/mule-uploader) library which checks for HTML5 APIs before continuing like so:

```
// verify that the browser has the needed HTML5 capabilities
if (!(namespace.File && namespace.FileList && namespace.Blob && namespace.FileReader && namespace.Worker)) {
    log("HTML5 APIs not available.");
    return -1;
}
```

Do the karma launchers support HTML5?

Comment: What you mean with `karma launchers`? Launchers are a couple of scripts that let karma spawn "clean" browsers instances to a specific page. There's no connection with browser abilities. Probably you should add the HTML5 check in your javascript list of files and execute it before running the suites.

Comment: @MarcoCI Can you elaborate on the last part? The check for the HTML5 APIs is in the mule uploader not in my code. By launchers i meant whether or not the launchers launched browsers that support HTML5. Guess so, right?

Answer (score 2):

A karma launcher is just a bunch of scripts (in JS, bash or Windows shell) to launch a program - effectively a browser - with some arguments in order to have a clean instance to use.

The HTML5 capability is something related to the browser itself and not to the script that is invoking it - as far as I know you cannot invoke a browser with a `--no-html5` flag.

Have a look at the source code of a karma launcher: [Chrome launcher](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-chrome-launcher/blob/master/index.js), [Firefox Launcher](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-firefox-launcher/blob/master/index.js), etc...

So between a karma launcher and the HTML5 there's no correlation as far as I know.

What it can happen is that the launcher is invoking an *old* version of the browser without the particular HTML5 capability you're looking for.

Try to set some logs in one of the launchers (there are usually no loggers in these plugins) and see the path they're pointing at: there should be a `DEFAULT_CMD` object with the paths for each OS defined in the file.

Comment: I see what you mean. Thanks for the info!